# I need to what is the value selected in a checkBox

Tags: apache-flex

```
<mx:CheckBox id="userlevel" x="118" fontSize="12" fontWeight="bold" y="127" label="Administrator"/>
```

What should be the Alert.show(userlevel.selected) returns whether its true or not... but i need the label value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

userlevel.label maybe?